# Grainy Markers with rotation in GoogleMaps

Tags: android, google-maps, canvas, rotation, markers

i've create a Maps with any images using this code:

```
icon_pin = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.arrow);
int w = icon_pin.getWidth();
int h = icon_pin.getHeight();
Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf); 


final float centerX = w / 2.0f;
final float centerY = h / 2.0f;

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
canvas.rotate(m.getDirection(), centerX, centerY);

canvas.drawBitmap(icon_pin, new Matrix(), null);
```

but when i rotated the image, the result is very grainy (like the green arrow in this example: http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/4624/screenshot2013052111381.png)

i've wrong something?
it's possibile bettering the definition?

Comment: Something about aliasing most probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to draw with anti-aliasing enabled.  In this line:

`canvas.drawBitmap(icon_pin, new Matrix(), null);`

You can specify a `Paint` object to use for drawing.  Above, you use `null`.  You can add these lines *before* your call to `canvas.drawBitmap()`:

```
Paint myPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
myPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
```

Then change your last line to:

`canvas.drawBitmap(icon_pin, new Matrix(), myPaint);`

This code creates a new `Paint` object with anti-aliasing enabled, which will hopefully take out the jagged edges on your markers.

Note:  You can also use `Paint` to apply colors, alpha shading and other cool effects to your drawing.  See the Android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html).